# how many device i can registered with single SENDER ID to Google cloud messeging service

Tags: android

I m using GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) service to send Push notifications to my android apps device. How many devices can i registered with `SINGLE SENDER ID`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number of devices, as well as you can use same Sender ID for different applications.

From the docs: `The sender ID is used in the registration process to identify a 3rd-party application server that is permitted to send messages to the device.`

So,

`Sender ID` idenitifies your server.

`Application ID` identifies each app.

`Registration ID` identifies each device.

For more information visit http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html